# Яндекс игры. Игра зависает после перехода по стики-баннеру

Tags: javascript, html, unity3d, web-apps, яндекс-игры

Делаю web игру на Unity для яндекс игр c помощью PluginYG.

1. Игра зависает или лагает при совершении игровых действий. Это нарушает пункт 1.14 требований платформы. Игра может зависать после перехода по стики-баннеру https://disk.yandex.ru/i/RG7aDn76oXvcSg  Nokia G20, Android 11 Приложение Яндекс 23.78 от 31 авг. 2023 сборка 230708003 721х1601

Я заметил, что после перехода по стики-баннеру игра открывается на весь экран, может это и вызывает ошибку, но я не понимаю как исправить. Прошу вас помочь с решением данной проблемы.

Comment: Удалось ли решить данную проблему? Столькнулся с ней сегодня игру отклонили. Игра нормально работает на мобильном Хроме. Но зависает именно на яндекс браузере. Если убрать флскрин и поставить его снова игра продолжает работать. Полазил нашел игру на юнити. После нажатия на стики банер и возврата она работате правда надо нажать пару раз на экран. Значит это можно на как то починить.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. До этого я билдил на юнити 21.и рандомные цифры. После перехода на юнити 22.3.7 и выше. В моем случае 22.3.9 все заработало. И игра больше не виснет на яндекс браузере. До этого висла именно на нем. Но билдится стало гораздо дольше по времени. Не знаю с чем связано